# Big query API has not been used in this project or has been disabled

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am running code that takes images from my drive and puts them into google slides. Also I am trying to export data from big query into a table in the same google slides doc. I keep getting this error though, but the API is enabled?

The issue seems to be with this line: 
 var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);

Also for some reason the big query data doesn't come into google slides as a table

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Generate Level B', 'showSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}


function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar')
  .setTitle('Generate Level B');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}



function showPrompt() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var result = ui.prompt(
    'Generate custom company slide',
    'Please enter the ticker symbol for the company:',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();

  var text = result.getResponseText();

  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    mergeSlide(text);

  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    return;
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    return;
  }
}

function test() {
  mergeSlide("DSYJ.J", "");}



function mergeSlide(tickerSymbol,companyName) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var dataTicker = flatten(sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow-2, 1).getValues());

  var dataName = flatten(sheet.getRange(3, 2, lastRow-2, 1).getValues());

  var dataDesc = flatten(sheet.getRange(3, 3, lastRow-2, 1).getValues());


  //Find index based on ticker/name

  if(tickerSymbol != ""){

    var index = dataTicker.indexOf(tickerSymbol);
    var companyDesc = dataDesc[index];  
    var companyName = dataName[index];  

  }else if(companyName != ""){

    var index = dataName.indexOf(companyName);
    var companyDesc = dataDesc[index];  
    var tickerSymbol = dataTicker[index]; 


  }else{

    return;

  }





  var slideUrl = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxx").makeCopy(companyName).getUrl();

  var slide = SlidesApp.openByUrl(slideUrl);

  var slides = slide.getSlides();



  //Slide1
  var shapesSlide1 = slides[0].getShapes();
  shapesSlide1[0].getText().setText(companyName);

  //Slide2
  var shapesSlide2 = slides[1].getShapes();
  shapesSlide2[0].getText().setText(companyDesc);


 //Slide3
  // Replace this value with the project ID listed in the Google Cloud Platform project.
  var projectId = 'vital-platform-791';
  var sqlQuery = 'SELECT Price FROM [vital-platform-791.feeds.chrome_blue_button_valuegrid_lookup] LIMIT 5';



  var request = {
    query: sqlQuery
  };

  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }

  // Get all the rows of results.
  var rows = queryResults.rows;
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
  }

  if (rows) {

    // Get the headers.
    var headers = queryResults.schema.fields.map(function(field) {
      return field.name;
    });

    // Get the results.
    var data = new Array(rows.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var cols = rows[i].f;
      data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
      }
    }

    var table = slides[2].insertTable(rows.length+1, headers.length);

    //Fill up the table header
    for(var m = 0; m< headers.length; m++){

      table.getCell(0,m).getText().setText(headers[m]).getTextStyle().setForegroundColor(255,0,86).setBold(true);

    }


    //Fill up rest of table
    for(var k = 1; k< rows.length+1; k++){

      for(var m = 0; m< headers.length; m++){

        table.getCell(k,m).getText().setText(data[k-1][m]);

      }

    }

  }



  //Slide4
  var shapeSlide4 = slides[3].getShapes();
  var priceChangeImage = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Price Change_"+tickerSymbol+".png").next();
  var newImage4 = shapeSlide4[0].replaceWithImage(priceChangeImage);
  newImage4.setWidth(650);
  newImage4.alignOnPage(SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

  //Slide5
  var shapeSlide5 = slides[4].getShapes();
  var earningsRevisionsImage = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Earnings Revisions_"+tickerSymbol+".png").next();
  var newImage5 = shapeSlide5[0].replaceWithImage(earningsRevisionsImage);
  newImage5.setWidth(650);
  newImage5.alignOnPage(SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

  //Slide6
  var shapeSlide6 = slides[5].getShapes();
  var FgpeImage = DriveApp.getFilesByName("F-GPE_"+tickerSymbol+".png").next();
  var newImage6 = shapeSlide6[0].replaceWithImage(FgpeImage);
  newImage6.setWidth(650);
  newImage6.alignOnPage(SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.HORIZONTAL_CENTER);


  newSlideNotify(slideUrl);

}



// Takes and array of arrays matrix and return an array of elements.
function flatten(arrayOfArrays){
  return [].concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays);
}


function newSlideNotify(url) {

  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutput('<p style="font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">A Level B report has been created for the company that you have selected.<br><br>This new file has been placed in the same folder with the Slide Template.<br><br></p><a href="'+url+'" target="_top" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Open Level B</a>')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setWidth(500)
  .setHeight(150);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Level B Generated!');

}





function getList() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var dataTicker = flatten(sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow-2, 1).getValues());
  var dataName = flatten(sheet.getRange(3, 2, lastRow-2, 1).getValues());

  return [dataTicker,dataName];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Advanced Service for BigQuery in your Google-Apps-script:

In [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery) about the BigQuery Service:

> Note: This is an advanced service that must be enabled before use.

...which redirects you to this link [where it explains how to enable advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced):

1. In the script editor, select Resources > Advanced Google services....
2. Click the on/off switch next to the service you want to use (in your case BigQuery API).
3. Click OK.

The next steps in the link explain you how to enable the API in the GOOGLE CLOUD PLATFORM Console (which I assume you have already done as you said that the API is already enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Does the error look like this?

> Access Not Configured. BigQuery API has not been used in project
>   5622793721 before or it is disabled. Enable it

If so, the problem is that you need to go to your Dashboard and enable it.

1. Open your script file
2. Go to Resources > Advanced Google Services
3. Notice the message saying *These services must also be enabled in the Google API Console.*
4. Click the link where it says [Google API Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library)
5. After searching for 'bigquery', do not select the one called Bigquery API. You are looking for the one called **BigQuery Data Transfer API**
6. Enable it
7. Run your code again to see if it works now
8. You may have to activate your email to the Analytics user management.

Comment: Could it be an issue with team drive? I created the script in team drive